# After calling a stored procedure by Entity Framework, tables update in database, but entities remain as they were

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I created two stored procedures in SQL Server Management Studio.

First procedure add field in ProjcetsToUsers table (for many-to-many associations)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addUserToProject
    @userId int,
    @projectId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;             
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ProjectsToUsers WHERE idProject = @projectId and idUser = @userId)  
        INSERT INTO ProjectsToUsers (idProject, idUser) VALUES (@projectId, @userId)    
END
GO
```

Second procedure delete field from this table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_deleteUserToProject
    @userId int,
    @projectId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;         
    DELETE FROM ProjectsToUsers WHERE idProject = @projectId and idUser = @userId       
END
GO
```

First function import update all date (in data base and entities in session):

```
Entities.AddUserToProject(projectId: project.id, userId: user.id);
```

Second function import update only field in data base =(

```
bugTrackerEntities.DeleteUserFromProject(projectId: project.id, userId: user.id);
```

I tried refresh entites:

```
bugTrackerEntities.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, project);
bugTrackerEntities.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, user);
bugTrackerEntities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
project.Users.Load();
user.Projects.Load();
```

it didn't help =(

**I can delete the user from the project and then add another, and the new one is added but removed the remains.
As for data base both this function work correctly.**

Why this happens?

Comment: Those are called **stored** procedures (as stored in SQL Server) - **not** storage procedures....

Answer (score 1):

If you have both user and project entities in your application you don't need these procedures at all. Simply use:

```
project.Users.Add(user);
```

And

```
project.Users.Remove(user);
```

The reason why this happens is that EF doesn't know that **relation** has changed. Try this to refresh relations:

```
bugTrackerEntities.LoadProperty<Project>(project, p => p.Users,  
    MergeOptions.OverwriteChanges);
```

I'm affraid that it will still have a problem with deleted relation - at least in version EFv1 (.NET 3.5 SP1) it [wasn't able to remove existing relation](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/03/11/adonet-entity-framework-unexpected-behaviour-with-mergeoptions/) which wasn't loaded from database.

Comment: Thank's, but LoadProperty is not hekpful. What about Add and Remove operation - this not work because "EF requires that each table must have primary key to be updatable. In your case you must".

Comment: Yes it requires so simply modify your junction table and add compound key from projectId and userId. It will not affect anything in your DB.